# WordPress Nexus Theme front-end editor broken because cannot find wp-load.php

Tags: wp-load.php

I’ve got a Nexus Theme (https://nexusthemes.com/) that stopped allowing me to edit through the frontend. Gives an “Error transferring data. Please try again later.” Console reports “Could not find wp-load.php (//) (), see nxs-ajax.php”“. It’s also breaking the theme’s contact form from submitting.

This started happening ever since the site was moved to Flywheel’s new cloud platform (Google Cloud). Now with the cloud platform, they move wp-admin and wp-includes into /.wordpress/. So the theme can no longer locate wp-load.php.

The theme file that looks for wp-load.php, is nxs-ajax.php (located in sftp.flywheelsites.com/clientname/clientsite/wp-content/themes/themename/nexusframework/stable/nexuscore/webservices/)

The nxs-ajax.php: https://gist.github.com/petebocken/90ca0099d1f48f6f08fbfab0d0235d49

I’ve been working with Flywheel support and they first suggested changing the WP_LOAD_PATH to “require_once(“../../../../.wordpress/wp-load.php”);” That did not help. They also suggested just removing that line entirely, but that didn't help either.

The nxs-ajax.php file has a bunch of if statements depending on where your files are located.

Answer (score 1):

Here was the fix supplied by Flywheel support. They went above and beyond to help me figure this out. Amazing!

```
<?php

    // let's load WordPress
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');

    //send_nosniff_header();

    nxs_ajax_webmethods();

    die();
?>
```